# Construct Array A of 1 and -1 of size N,such that sum of all A[i]*A[j] is Minimum and Positive. 1 <= i < j <= N

Tags: java, python, c++, arrays, algorithm

I came across this question in a competition. We have given a number N and we need to construct an array of size N which consists of 1 and -1 only, such that the value of sum of the product of each pair is minimum and Positive.
i.e. If the array is A then

> Sum of ( A[i] * A[j] ) over all 1 <= i < j <= N  is Minimum and Positive.

Example:

> Input => 3
>
> Output => [1,1,1]

Explanation - All possible cases are:

[1,1,1] = 3

[1,1,-1] = -1

[1,-1,-1] = - 1

[-1,-1,-1] = 3

And so all combination and the minimum possible positive case is 3.

How can we find such an array?

I tried to find a pattern but that did not worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analitically it's very simple, no need to write a program for it.

Let's notice, that:

```
(a1 + a2 + ... + an)^2 = (a1^2 + a2^2 + ... + an^2) + 2 * (a1a2 + a1a3 + ... + ana(n-1))
```

Or in other words (cannot format it here nicely):

```
(sum_{i}(ai))^2 = sum_{i}(ai^2) + 2 * sum_{1 <= i < j <= N}(ai * aj)
```

Here we're looking for `sum_{1 <= i < j <= N}(ai * aj)`.

After some simple additions we obtain:

```
sum_{1 <= i < j <= N}(ai * aj) = 1 / 2 * ((sum_{i}(ai))^2 - sum_{i}(ai^2))
```

Also notice, that `sum_{i}(ai^2)` is constant, since it's equal to `N` (only `-1` or `1`), thus the solution is when `(sum_{i}(ai))^2` is the smallest, so equal `0`, when `N` even and `1` when odd.

Solution:

1. For `N` even - any permutation of `N / 2` times `1` and `N / 2` times `-1`.
2. For `N` odd - any permutation of `(N - 1) / 2` times `1` and `(N + 1) / 2` times `-1` or `(N - 1) / 2` times `-1` and `(N + 1) / 2` times `1`.

Edit - for the minimum **positive** sum:

Having a base of:

```
sum_{1 <= i < j <= N}(ai * aj) = 1 / 2 * ((sum_{i}(ai))^2 - sum_{i}(ai^2)) = 1 / 2 * ((sum_{i}(ai))^2 - N)
```

we need to find ai, so that `(sum_{i}(ai))^2 > N => sum_{i}(ai) > sqrt(N)`.

If we have `ceil(sqrt(N))` times `1`, we have to distribute `N - ceil(sqrt(N)) = A` between `1` and `-1` to keep their sum smallest. Solution is obvoius:

1. For `A = 2 * B` => `B` times `1` and `-1`.
2. For `A = 2 * B + 1` => `B + 1` times `1` and `B` times `-1`.

Comment: This is a very good approach but actually I need a minimum POSITIVE sum. I think this is not satisfying my example I gave in problem statement.

Comment: @Kamesh-Bakshi sorry, I missed it, but basis is alright, check out my edit.

Comment: Okay, so we just need to solve a simple equation. Suppose positive no. of 1's and negative no. of -1's are in equation => [ positive - negative > sqrt(N) ].

Comment: What will be fasted way to decide this or to solve this equation as brute force will case worse.

Comment: Eh, i thought it's the easy part - added an edit.

Comment: Got it @Andronicus. Thanks.